# Firebase Firestore permissions working locally but not in production

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

**Situation**
I’m having some trouble with my Firebase Firestore rules. Everything works perfectly when my application is running locally — an authenticated user is allowed to write to Firestore. However, when I deploy to production, I am getting the error below.

**Error**
"FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions."

**Firestore Rules**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow create, update, delete: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what might be going on or how to debug the difference between prod and local? I'm logging user data to ensure auth is working in prod.

If I change the rules to "allow read, write: if true;" everything works fine in prod (just not secure).

Comment: You may check with this Article [How to fix Firestore Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) which will help you to understand everything you need to know about this error.

Comment: Firebase security rules don't do anything on their own. They only become active and gain meaning when you exercise code against them. Please edit your question to show the minimal code that any of us can run to get the problem. In that code, be sure to prove that it meets the requirements of your rules, i.e. check `if (getAuth().currentUser != null)` right before you call the database.

Answer (score 1):

As @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned in his comment, [Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) don't do anything on their own. The rules will work only when you start to perform queries against them. So if you see that some queries are starting to fail with a message that sounds like this:

> PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions

Then you're performing some queries that are rejected by the Firebase servers. Seeing the rules in your question, the reason why your queries are failing is that most likely your user is **not** authenticated. This means that you'll have to make sure the user is authenticated before performing the queries. To be 100% sure, check the user object against nullity in your application code:

```
if (getAuth().currentUser != null) {
    //Perfrom Firestore queries.
}
```

As @SandeepVokkareni mentioned in his comment, the following resource will help you better understand how Firebase Authentication, Firestore, and Security Rules can work together.

- [How to fix Firestore Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404)

Comment: Hey Dave. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?